# How should I design Navigation from SignIn/SignUp View Controllers?

Tags: android, ios, uinavigationcontroller, android-view

My app requires users to sign in or sign up upon the app loading. At the moment I have the flow so that there is a navigation controller controlling the sign In and sign Up VCs, and once the user successfully signsIn/Up (Via Parse), the VC pushes(show segue) to the Tab Bar Controller which is the main layout of the app.

This definitely doesn't seem like the right way to go about designing the navigation. It doesn't seem right to have to hide the back button for navigation upon entering the tab bar (from the sign in/up). How should I design this?

I realize that once I have a user saved locally I can set the rootview controller in the appDelegate to the tab Bar.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: It really depends on your app's requirement. If your app requires force login then I would suggest making sign-in/sign-up view controller as a `rootViewController` and after signing in you can set your tab-bar controller as the root, with a nice transition of course.

Comment: okay, how do I programatically set the view controller as the root after user signs in? @atulkhatri